# Infinite Binomial coefficient sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}$$

I am trying to do this, I think $|n| < 1$ is implied but Im not sure?

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

$$S = n! \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}$$

$$e^{1} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

But the $(n-k)!$ part makes it hard?

Comment: If $n$ is a nonnegative integer, then the sum is actually finite: $n \choose k$ is zero for $k>n$.

Comment: Hint: Binomial theorem makes evaluating the sum trivial.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2):

You are on the wrong way. 
The sum is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} -1= (1+1)^n-1=2^n-1$$

**EDIT** fixed formula!

Comment: It'll be $2^n-1$ for the given sum since summing starts at $k=1$.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you, i have fixed the formula...

Answer (score 1):

If your real question is 'what happens if $k>n$', then you need to use $convention$: by convention $\binom{n}{k}=0 \forall k>n$.